# Facebook Like Box (Page plugin) not working

Tags: html, facebook, plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've tried adding a facebook plugin to my page but it doesn't appear correctly.
What i've done so far was going to the Facebook Developpers for the new [Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin), included correctly (i hope) the SDK, included the script and pasted the html code the generator gave me.

But my Page Plugin is not working correctly, what i get is a simple orange block with a simple hyperlink redirecting to my fb page.
I couldn't find any help since they changed the possibility to switch between html5 xfbml and iframe. I thought it would be a css issue so i tried editing my div containing the Page plugin to disable some css proprieties but it didn't change a thing.
If i try adding an iframe code from another site on mine, it works fine, for example.

I really don't know where my issue comes from, i hope someone could help me !

(:

Comment: It's can be because the FB SDK isn't able to correctly calculate the dimensions for the FB content. It uses the parent element for it. It could be that it's not attached to the root HTML, when it's attached to it's parent (I had that problem a few times).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI JACRAC I FOUND THE SOLUTION IT TAKE ME SOMETIMES TO TEST IT AND IT WORKS THIS IS THE CODE YOU MUST ADD IN YOUR BLOG :

```
<div id="fbpage">
    <div id="u_0_18"><div fb-iframe-plugin-query="app_id=114545895322903&amp;container_width=588&amp;height=350&amp;hide_cover=false&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fisccef&amp;locale=fr_FR&amp;sdk=joey&amp;show_facepile=true&amp;show_posts=false&amp;width=280" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" class="fb-page fb_iframe_widget" data-show-posts="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-height="350" data-width="280" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/isccef"><span style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 280px; height: 191px;"><iframe class="" src="https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/plugins/page.php?app_id=114545895322903&amp;channel=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FQrU_tEEWym9.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df2b104c9e204ff8%26domain%3Ddevelopers.facebook.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdevelopers.facebook.com%252Ffad5f0e18965b4%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;container_width=588&amp;height=350&amp;hide_cover=false&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fisccef&amp;locale=fr_FR&amp;sdk=joey&amp;show_facepile=true&amp;show_posts=false&amp;width=280" style="border: medium none; visibility: visible; width: 280px; height: 191px;" title="fb:page Facebook Social Plugin" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" allowtransparency="true" name="f3d121ac9c81b02" frameborder="0" height="350px" width="280px"></iframe></span></div></div>
</div>
```

name your div you wana add the code into it also add this css code just to take control of your div , i named the dev fbpage :

```
#fbpage{
width: 280px;
height: 350px;
background-color: #e5e5e5;
 }
```

if you need any other help send me msg , have fun

Comment: I don't know how you did it but your code is working perfectly ! I would have enjoyed to know how you did it, but anyway thanks a lot !

Comment: no problem jacrac, i enjoy helping people :D  you can follow me on  twitter @HoussameM and we can exchange our knowledge .

Answer (score 0):

May be you have a misconfiguration in the Settings i think ! can seed us a screenshoot for verification

this is an example :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: hello, here is a screen that might help you helping me : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/22/1432899242-page-plugin.png

Answer (score 0):

It will work only when you upload the page on server. It you are testing it locally then it will not work.